# Remove write permission but keep delete permission

Tags: ubuntu, files, permissions, filesystems

This is an odd one, a file in my server is written to once every boot by one of the services  in it. I found out that another process (that I have no control of) keeps changing the contents, so I made the file immutable by adding `chattr -i filename` before my service writes to it and `chattr +i filename` afterwards.

This fixed the problem of the other process writing to the file, but unfortunately prevents the file from being deleted in a cleanup process (which happens in the case of a failure in the system).

I've tried using `chmod 0444` or `chmod a-w`, but neither of them seem to stop the other process from writing to it. Is there a way of adding delete permissions on top of `chattr +i` ?

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Stating what is the file (eg: /etc/resolv.conf or anything else) and the offending process (even if it's proprietary) could help devising alternate solutions. Especially if the offending process doesn't run as root.

Comment: It is actually  /etc/resolv.conf and the offending process is dhcpcd, I've added a hook to prevent it from writing on the file, but unfortunately, it starts at the very beginning on a server upgrade before the hook is written to it's conf file

Comment: Then this looks like an XY problem. That's a normal role for dhcpcd to update resolv.conf. You're trying Y: prevent dhcpcd to succeed at updating it, rather than X: how to have a correct content in resolv.conf? This requires more information of course (what are you trying to alter/not alter etc.)

Comment: IMHO it would be better to fix the issue rather than trying to do something about the symptoms. I.e., get the processes to update or not update the file rather than trying to protect the file.